# IMGUI High GPU usage

Tags: c++, directx, imgui

I just downloaded the imgui tests folder to make a small app.

Results are weird (in my opinion) 15%+ of GPU usage. (DX9 / DX11 tested)

So I downed the FPS to 60 for a quick test :

7/8%. Ok that's better but still seems a lot to me.

Is that normal ? How can I deal with this ? I've got a RTX 3090 so I don't really expect this to happen.

Some people say the app should take 1% or less of GPU especially with this GPU.

Thanks !

Comment: Open an issue in their tracker?

Comment: 7% gpu usage with what program? Some software only measure kernel time amd not gpu shader utilization. Maybe its not 7% of gpu but 7% of time even with 1 shader used at a time?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Checked in task manager and with afterburner.

Comment: ImGui works like most programs that use DirectX (games, etc.) ie: they use GPU and/or CPU even when it seems they're doing nothing because they just loop continuously on a "RenderFrame" or similar method that rewrites the whole screen. The rationale for these programs is you kinda own the GPU because the screen *will/should* be redrawn all the time. They don't work like for example WPF (also based on DirectX version 9) which only redraws what's needed when it's needed. Changing this behavior cannot be done, it would require a complete rearchitecture.